# Coded UI Mouse Click of Html button is not working

Tags: c#, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm working on a Coded UI Test project that tests an MVC application, I did write some manual code to test a page and unfortunately the Mouse.Click is not firing up and the same is also failing with generated code.

It would be really helpful if someone could shed a little light on this issue.

```
Mouse.Click(btnLogin, btnLogin.GetClickablePoint());
```

Exception messages are,

```
Cannot perform 'Click' on the control. Additional Details:
TechnologyName:  'Web'
ControlType:  'Button'
TagName: 'BUTTON'
Id:  'btnLogin'
Name:  ''
DisplayText:  'Log in'
Type:  'submit'
```

Inner Exception reads as below

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

**EDIT**
I just found what caused exception but couldn't find a solution. I'm working on a dual monitor and Mouse.Click is not working when I'm using both monitors, I turned one monitor off and got it working perfectly.

Comment: I'm interested to know why using two monitors would cause an exception like that. Let us know if you find out anything.